# Navigation from Tabpage in prism in xamarinforms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

When Navigating From tabpage the navigation bar is not visible.
My tab page looks like this

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <local:ViewA  Icon="a.png" Title=""/>
    <local:ViewB Icon="b.png" Title=""/>
    <local:ViewC Icon="c.png" Title=""/>

</TabbedPage.Children>
public partial class BottomTabPage : PlatformTabbedPage, INavigatingAware
{
public BottomTabPage()
{
InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            (child as INavigatingAware)?.OnNavigatingTo(parameters);
            (child?.BindingContext as INavigatingAware)?.OnNavigatingTo(parameters);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now when navigating from ViewA content page Navigation bar is not visible on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you get a navigation bar is if you are navigating within a NavigationPage.  If your TabbedPage is within a NavigationPage, make sure you are forcing an async (non-modal) navigation by setting the useModalNavigation to false in the INavigationService.NavigateAsync method.